# Unable to join Telegram channel after Using Banchatmember

Tags: telegram

I'm using a telegram bot to maintain a private group, where I kick the user accordingly.
It works great but then comes this issue, When I use `bot.ban_chat_member(user_id, chat_id)` or `bot.kick_chat_member(user_id, chat_id)` to remove a user from the chat I can't add the user back again.

After I use `bot.unban_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)` and send an invite link to the user that I kicked, The user can't join the group. It shows that the channel is private and the user should wait for admin approval.

The only way allowed to join the group is by using an invite link generated by the bot.

What is the issue? How can I fix it? I can't afford anything else except the invite link generated by the bot.